# How to setup push notifications in Swift + Azure Hub?

Tags: ios, swift, azure, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I'm developing an app for iOS 9. I want to setup push notification with Azure Hub in swift. I followed following tutorial too which is in Obj-C.I converted it to Swift. but getting error as follows:

> Error registering for notification: Error Domain=WindowsAzureMessaging
>   Code=403 "URLRequest failed for  {
>   URL: URL.servicebus.windows.net/Not... } with status code: forbidden"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=URLRequest failed for
>    { URL:
>   URL.servicebus.windows.net/Not... } with status code: forbidden}

Comment: Did you redact your error message or is it exactly how it was? Because if you're trying to connect to `URL.servicebus.windows.net/Not...` unless your Notification Hubs namespace name is URL it is going to fail. Make sure you're connecting to the right hub.

Comment: @Nikita G Yes I edit my URL here.But I have connected to the right hub.

Answer (score -1):

[This resource](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push/) contains an example for creating push notifications using Azure Notification Hub for Swift (you don't have to translate from Obj-C to Swift since there already is an example available).

It basically builds on the [iOS app with the Azure back-end](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started/) and adds push notifications for every item added.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not using a Azure backend but I'm using Azure Notification hub just to send push notifications.
So i think i don't need ClientManager isn't it?

Comment: I think you still need `ClientManager` since it is used in `AppDelegate.swift`.

Comment: which url should i enter for the client manager? since i don't use azure would it be ok to add any other url instead of an azure url? please explain